# Pause and resume using Receive Task in Activiti 7

Tags: alfresco, activiti, bpmn

We are trying to use receive task in activiti version 7.0.0SR1 to wait for callback from external system. 
After receiving callback, we want to resume the paused workflow.

When I looked at activiti 7 (which unfortunately doesn;t have enough documentation compared to Activiti 6), couldn't figure out how to achive this.
There are post in Alfresco community that currently ReceiveTask doesn's support this - 
https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/issues/2152

Activity 6 uses Receive task or ReceiveTaskActivityBehavior via Spring integration route to do this.

I've couple of questions regarding this -
1) Any pointers related to the problem above greatly appreciated, also do point out if my modelling needs correction.
2) Is it too early to use Activiti 7? Should I bettre stick to Activity 6, looks better in terms of documentation and more stable as well, 
   my experience with resources available on v7 is not great, more inclined towards v6, any suggestions here?

Answer (score 0):

To Suspend a process :

```
getProcessEngine(delegateExecution).getRuntimeService().suspendProcessInstanceById(delegateExecution.getProcessInstanceId());
```

To Resume a process :

```
getProcessEngine().getRuntimeService().activateProcessInstanceById(processInstanceId);
getProcessEngine().getRuntimeService().trigger(latestExecutionID, workflowVariables);
```